# Not able to send post request to my express API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

I am sending a post request to my Heroku API, but receiving nothing in return.

This is where I am making the request:

```
const [ user, setUser] = useState({
    email:"",
    password:""
})

const handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    setUser({
        ...user,
        [name]: value
    })
}

const login = () => {
    axios.post("https://<myherokuapp>/login", user)
    .then(res => {
        alert(res.data.message)
        setLoginUser(res.data.user)
        navigate("/")
    })
}
```

This is the body of the request:

```
app.post("/login", (req, res)=> {
    const { email, password} = req.body
    User.findOne({ email: email}, (err, user) => {
        if(user){
            if(password === user.password ) {
                res.send({message: "Login Successfull", user: user})
            } else {
                res.send({ message: "Password didn't match"})
            }
        } else {
            res.send({message: "User not registered"})
        }
    })
}) 

app.post("/register", (req, res)=> {
    const { name, email, password} = req.body
    User.findOne({email: email}, (err, user) => {
        if(user){
            res.send({message: "User already registerd"})
        } else {
            const user = new User({
                name,
                email,
                password
            })
            user.save(err => {
                if(err) {
                    res.send(err)
                } else {
                    res.send( { message: "Successfully Registered, Please login now." })
                }
            })
        }
    })
    
})
```

This is the index.js running on heroku:

```
import express from "express"
import cors from "cors"
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 9002;
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(cors())

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://<myDbLink>.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, () => {
    console.log("DB connected")
})

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
})

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema)

//Routes
app.post("/login", (req, res)=> {
    const { email, password} = req.body
    User.findOne({ email: email}, (err, user) => {
        if(user){
            if(password === user.password ) {
                res.send({message: "Login Successfull", user: user})
            } else {
                res.send({ message: "Password didn't match"})
            }
        } else {
            res.send({message: "User not registered"})
        }
    })
}) 

app.post("/register", (req, res)=> {
    const { name, email, password} = req.body
    User.findOne({email: email}, (err, user) => {
        if(user){
            res.send({message: "User already registerd"})
        } else {
            const user = new User({
                name,
                email,
                password
            })
            user.save(err => {
                if(err) {
                    res.send(err)
                } else {
                    res.send( { message: "Successfully Registered, Please login now." })
                }
            })
        }
    })
    
}) 
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("get is working")
})
app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log("BE started at port")
})
```

When I tried in my localhost , it was working fine , but now it is giving me an error **user is not registered** , even when I have the user in my database. Please help me solve this problem , this is the first time I am using heroku with nodejs.

Comment: Can you share the request body of the POST request you are sending from the UI

Comment: Check error arg on the login endpoint.

Comment: Check in the developer tools of your browser, if the request really has the expected body. The code on the server side seems fine, so if the request's body actually contains a value for `email` and it still returns "not registered", chances are high, that  there is no user with that email in the database. Also check the `err` object. Maybe there is an error in the connection to mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

Your route code is correct but the approach of hosting a website on Heroku is wrong, you should need to connect DB with Atlas Cluster for more detail and follow up on the official documentation [Host Website on Heroku that uses Mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/use-atlas-on-heroku/)